# Native method not found make.so, failed during runtime

Tags: android, c++

I have tried to use native method in my android application. My situation is that I have developed, so successfully, but during the runtime, it notes that native method cannot be found.

After research on the Internet, I have checked some problems.
First, I have use extern "C" in `.cpp`
[.cpp](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GVaC4.png)

Second I have checked the package name, class name.
[class](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pLR3B.png)
Third I have assured that directory of my program.

Can anyone help?

Comment: Your jni method signature should use  correct package name of your Java class

Comment: Please paste code directly into your question rather than posting a link to a screenshot; most people here will skip past these kinds of questions.

Comment: I think I have used correct package name.

Comment: Better explained.